# Datalab - how to install and keep packages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I decided to try and use Google Cloud Datalab for a small project that I'm working on rather than a Jupyter Notebook in an Anaconda environment on an AWS instance.

How can I install a package (for example OpenCV) onto the Datalab VM so that I don't have to reinstall it every time I restart my VM? Why do the packages disappear after every restart but the updated notebooks remain persistent? Any help answering these questions and clarifying how the Datalab VM works would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The notebooks are stored in a docker volume mount that represents a location on the persistent disk that is maintained across restarts of the VM.

The packages you install however are stored in the running container and hence lost on each restart.

You could create a custom docker image and use that instead. On the `datalab create` command, see the `--image-name` argument.

Here is an example of a Dockerfile you'll want to use:

```
FROM gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:latest
RUN pip install opencv
```

Note that you'll need build the docker image using this docker file, and push the image to Google Container Registry. My memory is a bit fuzzy on this, but it is possible this image needs to be marked as public.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, Nikhil! This being said, I'm struggling to see the advantages of using Datalab as opposed to just installing Conda on a Compute Engine VM and running Jupyter notebooks off of there. That way I could easily install new packages and have them stay on the instance persistently. I still don't understand why would I want to use Datalab in this case? I read the documentation, but this is still unclear.

Comment: @haroon7 I can think of two benefits: one is the integration with git repos allowing to share work among colleagues; the other, the possibility of changing the backend more easily than having to deploy a new VM, install python, configure the development environment, etc.